# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de gerar o HTML no cliente ou servidor?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Historicamente, o HTML quase sempre foi gerado no servidor, sendo o Javascript usado para poucas coisas, como animações, validações, máscaras, etc.

Porém, nos últimos tempos nasceu uma tendência de gerar o HTML (quase) totalmente no cliente, usando Javascript.

Eu particularmente sou meio cético quanto a essa tendência, devido a problemas como:

- O desenvolvimento e manutenção é mais trabalhoso;
- Leva mais tempo;
- É difícil atingir testabilidade;
- O Javascript não tão intuitivo pra essas coisas como uma boa ferramenta de template no servidor;
- Poucas pessoas têm o conhecimento dessa técnica;
- Difícil compatibilidade entre *browsers*;
- Entre outros.

Mas eu gostaria de uma opinião de quem têm mais experiência no assunto. Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de gerar o HTML no cliente? E no servidor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Separar ou não o HTML (*front-end*) do *back-end* não pode ser considerado boa nem má pratica de maneira universal, isto depende do escopo do seu projeto, do tipo de profissionais que você tem à disposição, do quanto está disposto a investir, entre outras coisas. E como todas as metodologias de desenvolvimento, existem vantagens e desvantagens:

> ## Principais vantagens:
>
> - Independência entre cliente e servidor;
> - Utilização de recursos diferentes;
> - Foco restrito a cada àrea

**Independência entre cliente e servidor:**

Separando as camadas cliente e servidor, de forma que eles se comuniquem apenas via API (REST, por exemplo) você cria uma independência total e previne retrabalho caso seu back-end precise de algum tipo de alteração.

Por exemplo: Você criou um projeto na linguagem X, mas o projeto escalou de tal forma, que você agora precisa transcrever grande parte dele para a linguagem Y para conseguir mais performance. Isto muitas vezes acarreta na perda do sistema de templates que você utilizava, mas com o cliente independente do servidor, você teria ele da mesma forma e só teria que tomar o cuidado de expor e manter as mesmas APIs na nova linguagem.

**Utilização de recursos diferentes:**

Por mais que as pessoas ainda subestimem a parte de UI e UX de um projeto, fica cada dia mais evidente que esta é uma das mais importantes partes no escopo de um projeto. Mas o problema é que a maioria dos profissionais que trabalham com UI e UX não são programadores back-end, e vice-versa.

Ou seja, se você utiliza um sistema de templates próprio da sua linguagem, ou gera as telas no seu código, dificilmente conseguirá alguém para criar telas pensando nos princípios de usabilidade e experiência final. Agora, *emancipando* o front-end e deixando o seu desenvolvimento para profissionais especializados, isto não mais é um problema visto que o mercado de Designers e Desenvolvedores Front-end tem experiência (dentre outras) justamente nas linguagens HTML, CSS e JavaScript.

**Foco restrito a cada área:**

Acompanhando a vantagem acima, este tópico representa o fato de ter diferentes profissionais para diferentes tarefas. Assim como você não coloca o engenheiro para decorar a sala de estar de um prédio, não se deve colocar um programador back-end (que cuida da lógica do sistema) para criar telas, visual e lógica no front-end de um sistema. Separando as areas (back-end e front-end) você consegue deixar cada lado mais livre para trabalhar de forma centrada em sua área, sem misturar os lados e as tarefas de cada profissional.

> ## Principais desvantagens:
>
> - Custo elevado;
> - Gestão mais complexa;
> - Risco de qualidade.

**Custo elevado:**

O seu projeto que tinha uma equipe de desenvolvimento, agora tera mais um braço focado no lado front-end. Por um lado isto desafogaria um pouco os programadores back-end, mas por outro, teria o custo adicional de novos desenvolvedores, uma nova equipe e um eventual gestor para a nova área *(ver próximo tópico)*;

**Gestão mais complexa:**

Como dito acima, mais um "setor" pode acarretar na necessidade de mais um gestor focado apenas na equipe de front-end. O projeto agora teria duas frentes que andariam independentes, mas ao mesmo tempo tendo a necessidade de ter sincronia para uma comunicação harmoniosa entre os lados cliente e servidor.

**Risco de qualidade:**

Este problema pode ocorrer tanto no back-end como no front-end, mas caso não seja feito um acompanhamento e gerenciamento de bom nível, ou caso o profissional contratado não seja de fato de qualidade, é possível que você tenha um front-end bagunçado e de difícil manutenção e escalabilidade, o que te traria mais prejuízos (de tempo e dinheiro) do que vantagens.

---

Como dito la no início, separar ou não o front-end depende muito do contexto em que está o seu projeto. E você deve levar em consideração que o custo e gestão podem ser mais pesados inicialmente, mas se forem feitos com planejamento, podem ter bons resultados a longo prazo.

Answer (score 4):

## Qual o requisito?

A concorrência da web faz com que cada vez mais o diferencial das aplicações esteja na usabilidade ou UX (*User Experience*).

A interação e o tempo de resposta são requisitos prioritários para o usuário moderno, adepto desde cedo dos *smartphones* e outros dispositivos *smart*.

E essa tendência é justificada no fato de que é necessário agradar ao usuário e, ao mesmo tempo, seria inviável enviar requisições ao servidor a cada interação com a interface gráfica (UI - *User Interface*).

## Quanto aos pontos levantados

> O desenvolvimento e manutenção é mais trabalhoso

Sim, mas resultados mais elaborados quase sempre são mais trabalhosos. As indústrias sempre começa com produtos mais simples e acrescentam camadas de complexidade ano após ano, na medida em que as tecnologias amadurecem.

> Leva mais tempo

Sim, mas o mesmo é verdade quando sempre que queremos mais qualidade, mais desempenho ou qualquer outro quesito técnico.

> É difícil atingir testabilidade

Sim, mas também é mais fácil testar uma bicicleta do que um avião, no entanto, as empresas que fabricam o última faturam muito mais.

O que quero dizer, é que complexidade sempre aumenta a dificuldade de testes, mas o custo adicional é um preço a se pagar para maiores recompensas.

> O Javascript não tão intuitivo pra essas coisas como uma boa ferramenta de template no servidor

Sim, porém a tendência é mudar. Concordo que quase todos os frameworks que se propõe a gerar ou abstrair o HTML ou CSS acabam sendo um pesadelo no final. Mas cedo ou tarde alguém acerta em cheio. (Já viu o [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/)?)

> Poucas pessoas têm o conhecimento dessa técnica

Sim, porém isso é justamente o diferencial. Empresas com visão de futuro e que investem em tecnologia (não é muito a realidade aqui no Brasil) preferem investir numa UX acima da média de modo a manterem uma vantagem competitiva.

> Difícil compatibilidade entre browsers

Esta é uma realidade em sistemas mais dinâmicos ou mais estáticos. Mas, assim como o jQuery revolucionou de certa forma essa questão de compatibilidade, o mesmo resultado pode ser alcançado com bibliotecas como Angular.js e outras que estão nesta categoria.

## Conclusão

Embora o cenário de desenvolvimento de aplicações web esteja cada vez mais complexo, esta é uma tendência que veio para ficar, dada a grande concorrência entre aplicações de altíssima qualidade disponíveis hoje.

Cabe, entretanto, a nós desenvolvedores pensarmos e repensarmos em meios mais produtivos e seguros de progredir tecnologicamente ao invés de tentarmos nos agarrar na segurança do que é "tradicional".